# Can not open android database using SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()

Tags: android, database-connection, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

In my app, I tried to open existing android database for modifying its content by following code:

```
    String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider/databases/";
    String DB_NAME = "logs.db";

    ..........................

  SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Path to database is correct, I also changed permission for database file. But there is always an error "Fail to open database file (code 14):, while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode"

my manifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.logsfiller"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.logsfiller.LogFillerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Did I make something wrong? Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Check permissions of your application (you need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and try to use another method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6781029/1001401

I think - you can use method of context: Context.openOrCreateDatabase: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: I did it already, but same issue :|

Comment: Do you create DB before opening? Or do you create directory "/databases/"?

Comment: could You post Your manifest.xml?

Comment: @nfirex This DB is belong to others application, Now I want to access and modify it.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs My manifest file now is very simple, because of I could not access database for further action :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't mention the extension of the db

Try this, it will work.

```
String DB_NAME = "logs";
```

**EDIT :**

Add this class to your program,

```
public class DBAdapter {

final Context context;
DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "logs", null, 1);
    }
}

public DBAdapter open(String path, String dbName) throws SQLException {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String destPath = path + "/" + dbName;
        db = db.openDatabase(destPath, null, 0);
        return this;
    }
}
```

and call `open()` method like,

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider/databases/";
String DB_NAME = "logs";

db.open(DB_PATH, DB_NAME);
```

it works for me, surely it work for you

Comment: I did it, now PRAGMA journal_mode is not shown, But still error: "unknown error (code 14): Could not open database :|

Comment: whether the db path and the db name is coorect & check whether the db is existing in the device path

Comment: @Achuthan I checked, db path and db name are correct and db is exist. I have rooted deivce, so I can check /data/data folder

Comment: Thank for all your help. BUT, this error may comes from kernel since i saw this in Logcat "(14) os_unix.c:30241: "
This issue may can not be fixed.
Thank you anyway!!!