# Making a copy of Android database

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

I've been trying to create a copy of the applications database and save it onto the root of the phone, but no luck. My logs go:

**STEP ONE**

**STEP DEAD**

Apparently `if (sd.canWrite())` is the first mistake? Can anyone help with this? I'm running out of ideas. Thanks

```
public void save() {


        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
        sd.mkdirs();
        Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "STEP ONE");
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "STEP TWO");
            String currentDBPath = "/data/com.test.example/databases/example_db";
            String backupDBPath = "/mytest" + "version_two" + ".db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
            Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "STEP THREE");
            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "STEP FOUR");
                FileChannel src;
                try {
                    Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "STEP FIVE");
                    src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB)
                            .getChannel();
                    try {
                        Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "STEP SIX");
                        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                        src.close();
                        dst.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "STEP ONE DEAD");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "STEP TWO DEAD");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "STEP DEAD");
        }

    }
```

**Clip of my manifest - I don't know how `android:allowBackup="true"` got there**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
```

On emulator output:

```
01-13 14:16:13.082: D/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(30105): STEP ONE
01-13 14:16:13.082: D/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(30105): STEP DEAD
```

On device output:

```
01-13 14:16:13.082: D/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(30105): STEP ONE
01-13 14:16:13.082: D/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(30105): STEP TWO
01-13 14:16:13.082: D/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(30105): STEP THREE
01-13 14:16:13.082: D/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(30105): STEP FOUR
01-13 14:16:13.082: D/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(30105): STEP FIVE
01-13 14:16:13.090: D/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(30105): STEP SIX
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580683/writing-text-file-to-sd-card-fails

Comment: Also this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder/3551906#3551906. Shouldn't you be specifying a filename as well? It seems that you're only using the directory for creating the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
```

Well, since Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns a File you do not to create a new instance.You can change it in this way:

```
 File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

- `sd.mkdirs();` will sure fail, because you have not write permission inside  `/` and `/mnt`, also the directory pointed by `sd` should already exits
- Write permission - `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` : did you add it inside your AndroidManifex file? Probably canWrite() returns false because you forgot to add the permission

Comment: Hmm... I just added it, and I thought it would work, but still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: I still get STEP ONE then STEP DEAD. Urg... any other ideas?

Comment: but do you have a sdcard in your mobile?

Comment: I'm trying this on an emulator...

Is that my problem? oh no. I should've known. I'll go try that right now.

Comment: Yeah, it worked on the actual device. Thank you so much for troubleshooting this with me. I appreciate it.